# Unable To Find Column

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net

Why does the following statement turn false?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=connection;Uid=root;password=;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
        MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "Select number from user where id=1";
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader["text"].ToString());

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Here is my db:
Database name: connection
Table Name: user

```
number: 18.81
id: 1
```

Comment: You load a column named number but then search for a column named text?

Comment: However I don't understand what is the statement that returns FALSE. As is now, or you don't have any record with ID=1 or this code will throw an exception at the read["text"] code.

Answer (score 2):

You are currently selecting only `number` field from database, but trying to read `text` field from result set. Either add `text` field to select statement (if you want to get text from database):

```
command.CommandText = "Select text from user where id=1";
```

Or read `number` from result set (I think you need this solution, if table structure you described is correct):

```
Console.WriteLine(reader["number"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parametrized query your query is open to SQL Injection.

in your sql select statement `Select number from user where id=1` you are selecting number but in reader you are trying to access text which is wrong try this code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string connString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=connection;Uid=root;password=;";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
    MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "Select number from user where id=@Id";
    command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters["@Id"].Value = 1;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader["number"].ToString());

    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```